# Go - How to load a new html form

Tags: go

After processing a jQuery Ajax Post from an HTML form successfully within a Go program, how do I load a new form? I first tried sending the form as the response and the Javascript displayed it, but it did not clear the old (existing) form. I then tried within the HTML Javascript to set the URL using "window.location = 'localhost:8088/MaintForm/'". That resulted in a warning from the browser but did not load the form and did not change the URL. I would like to ideally know both methods - via the Go program acting as a server, and via Javascript. If I manually change the URL, the form loads OK. What I am trying to do is receive a response in Javascript (jQuery Ajax), and then request the new form if the response is positive. I would prefer to do this without changing the URL. As I said above, this partially worked.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to put your original form inside a tag, for example a div, and use your JQuery code to replace the contents of that tag with the new form.  This way you are not changing the URL.

This is more of a javascript/JQuery question than a go-specific one.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript:

```
location.href = '/MaintForm/';
```

In golang, you can use the [`http.Redirect`](http://golang.org/pkg/http/#Redirect) function, like this:

```
http.Redirect(w, r, "/MaintForm/", http.StatusFound)
```

Comment: Thanks for that info. I will look at that API, but currently the Go application serving the pages is fairly minimalist and I would prefer to just serve the page in response to an Ajax GET via jQuery. I don't want to keep changing the URL, at least not unless that becomes the "best" way to do it. Currently the only imports are :("http"; "os"; "io/ioutil"; "fmt"; "time").

Comment: Found the solution that solves what I need initially. After sending the form from Go in response to an $.ajax POST or GET, I just need to do an "document.write(data);" in Javascript. Still haven't found out why the "window.location = 'localhost:8088/MaintForm/'" did not work. The browser issues a warning but doesn't appear to change the URL. Not sure why it issues the warning, because it is the same domain.

Comment: `window.location` is a Location object.  You should modify `window.location.href` to redirect.  You should post your solution as an answer and accept it since it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please note: this appears to be solved by : I just need to do an "document.write(data);" in Javascript. "Data" contains the new HTML.

Comment: I should add that @hyperslug's explanation to use "window.location.href" in Javascript also works. I am undecided which method I will use, perhaps the former (sending the HTML), because in a commercial application I do not want users navigating all over the place via URLs. Just testing for now.